# Unit-testing: Mocking a subprocess running "aws s3 sync" with Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, amazon-s3, mocking, subprocess

My project needs to download quite a few files regularly before doing treatment on them.
I tried coding it directly in Python but it's horribly slow considering the amount of data in the buckets.

I decided to use a subprocess running `aws-cli` because `boto3` still doesn't have a sync functionality. I know using a subprocess with `aws-cli` is not ideal, but it really is useful and works extremely well out of the box.

One of the perks of `aws-cli` is the fact that I can see the progress in `stdout`, which I am getting with the following code:

```
def download_bucket(bucket_url, dir_name, dest):
"""Download all the files from a bucket into a directory."""
path = Path(dest) / dir_name
bucket_dest = str(os.path.join(bucket_url, dir_name))
with subprocess.Popen(["aws", "s3", "sync", bucket_dest, path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
    for b in p.stdout:
        print(b, end='')

if p.returncode != 0:
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(p.returncode, p.args)
```

Now, I want to make sure that I test this function but I am blocked here because:

1. I don't know the best way to test this kind of freakish behavior:

   - Am I supposed to actually create a fake local s3 bucket so that `aws s3 sync` can hit it?
   - Am I supposed to mock the subprocess call and not actually call my `download_bucket` function?

Until now, my attempt was to create a fake bucket and to pass it to my download_bucket function.
This way, I thought that `aws s3 sync` would still be working, albeit locally:

```
def test_download_s3(tmpdir):
tmpdir.join(f'frankendir').ensure()
with mock_s3():
    conn = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-east-1')
    conn.create_bucket(Bucket='cool-bucket.us-east-1.dev.000000000000')

    s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name="us-east-1")
    s3.put_object(Bucket='cool-bucket.us-east-1.dev.000000000000', Key='frankendir', Body='has no files')

    body = conn.Object('cool-bucket.us-east-1.dev.000000000000', 'frankendir').get()[
        'Body'].read().decode("utf-8")

    download_bucket('s3://cool-bucket.us-east-1.dev.000000000000', 'frankendir', tmpdir)

    #assert tmpdir.join('frankendir').join('has not files').exists()
    assert body == 'has no files'
```

But I get the following error `fatal error: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListObjects operation: The AWS Access Key Id you  provided does not exist in our records.`

My questions are the following:

1. Should I continue to pursue this creation of a fake local s3 bucket?

   - If so, how am I supposed to get the credentials to work?
2. Should I just mock the subprocess call and how?

   - I am having a hard time understanding how mocking works and how it's supposed to be done. From my understanding, I would just fake a call to `aws s3 sync` and return some files?
3. Is there another kind of unit test that would be enough that I didn't think of?

   - After all, I just want to know if when I transmit a well-formed `s3://bucketurl`, a `dir` in that bucket and a `local dir`, the files contained within the `s3://bucketurl/dir` are downloaded to my `local dir`.

Thank you for your help, I hope that I am not all over the place.

Comment: The only code I see a need to test is the iteration over *some* iterable of strings. Creating a bucket just helps verify that `aws-cli` works, but that's not really in the scope of testing *your* function. I would mock `subprocess.Popen`, verifying that it receives the correct bucket name as an argument, and configure it to produce an appropriate iterable for `p.stdout` and a return status to test the error handling.

Answer (score 0):

A much better approach is to use [moto](https://pypi.org/project/moto/) when faking / testing s3. You can check out their documentation or look at a test code example I did: https://github.com/pksol/pycon-go-beyond-mocks/blob/main/test_s3_fake.py.

If you have a few minutes, you can view [this short video](https://youtu.be/N_9qu5U88Qg?t=787) of me explaining the benefits of using moto vs trying to mock.

Comment: Hey, Peter, I am going to check that out later this week. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Peter, this answer doesn't handle the fact that a subprocess is being used to call S3.  Is it possible to use moto in this case?